# How to create dynamic arrays in perl

Tags: perl

I have a situation where input is in form of
`$n` followed by `n` lines having elements of `n` different arrays.
like

```
2  
1 2 3   
1 6
```

means i have 2 arrays with elements as `1,2,3` and `1,6`.

Now i really dont know how big N can be. How to create dynamic arrays and store value to them. Arrays may be named array1,array2 or any other method to differentiate different arrays.

```
$n = <STDIN>;
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    $l   = <STDIN>;
    @arr = split(" ", $l);
}
```

Please improve this code.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html

Comment: There is no such thing as dynamic arrays in Perl. You may be thinking of multi-dimensional arrays. Storing the values is only half the problem, though, the question is what you want to do with the values.

Comment: Perl arrays are not limited in size. Any array is "dynamic" according to your description.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array of arrays:

```
use strict;    
my @array;
while(<STDIN>) {
    my @line = split(" ", $_);
    push @array, \@line;
}

# Just to display what's inside your array:
use Data::Dumper;     
print Dumper(\@array);
```

Or even shorter:

```
use strict;
my @array;
push @array, [split ' ', $_] while(<STDIN>);
```

Comment: `print Dumper \@array`